Why are my dual boot partitions in differents disks in disk management window, and how to delete one
Long ago I partitioned my SSD [mounted on NVME] to dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows (I normally boot with the GRUB loader). I want to delete the Ubuntu partition, but I don't get why I have them on different disks, according to the Disk Management (I also seem to have two recovery partitions?):
EDIT: Long ago I bought a new SSD [mounted on NVME] to dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows (I normally boot with the GRUB loader). I want to delete Ubuntu in the Ubuntu drive, but I think the boot partition is only in the Ubuntu disk:  
How must I proceed (I'm quite noob at this)?

When OSes reside on different drives, it's recommended to have a boot partition for each OS on their respective drives since it still allows booting if one of the drives is removed. To remove Ubuntu, delete the two partitions on its drive, then to ensure Windows still boots without issue, mount the EFI partition on the Windows drive via diskpart to Z:, then BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Z: /f UEFI (I'm assuming this is a UEFI machine since the boot partitions are FAT32 - also, you'll want to move the boot partition for Windows in front of the OS partition and move WinRE to its own partition)

(Cont'd...) It's entirely possible the partition following the Windows OS partition is a WinRE partition, however unlikely since the WinRE partition is always NTFS, whereas the EFI partition is always FAT32 (it is a bit odd though for a boot partition to be 520MB). If this machine was an upgrade to Windows 10, it's for sure a boot partition since WinRE is only placed into its own partition when clean installing Win10 (unless manually moved, it was located prior to at C:\<Recovery | WindowsRE>). list disk (GPT is EFI boot) and detail partition in diskpart would provide more info

Are you still able to reboot into Ubuntu? Can you paste the output of lsblk there?

@JW0914 yes, this machine was an upgrade from win7 to win10. The 520 MB partition says "recovery partition", so it must be that.
The only problem I see about deleting the two partitions on the Ubuntu drive is that the 512 MB one may be shared by windows to boot, so if I delete my windows will have no boot partition xD
I fiddled with diskpart, here are the results
(image) https://prnt.sc/MPGfxaeVAToi
Disk 0 is the ubuntu one, Disk 2 is the windows one

(cont'd) I also have no Z: drive, I tried C:\>z: and got "The system can't find the specified controller"

(also more info with bcdedit on the windows disk https://prnt.sc/Ja5iBjrBWiCd)

Since you have NVME, I'm assuming it's a UEFI motherboard? If so, the Windows drive should be converted to GPT using mbr2gpt in WinRE. You can create a boot partition on the drive Windows is installed on, and since you're using MBR, shrink the OS partition by 100MB, format it as FAT32, mark it as active, mount it at Z:, then BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Z: /f All If it doesn't boot, boot a Windows install USB, Shift+F10 to open a terminal, then: bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /fixboot && bootrec /rebuildbcd. Add any Windows installs it finds, and even if it doesn't, reboot once it completes
